# How to get meta information from Bigcommerce Order v2 endpoint

Tags: python, bigcommerce

I need to build some BI reports on top of big commerce. I am trying to pull all information related to Order v2. As there is a limitation that it will return only 50 records at a time. I am trying to get the meta-information that can tell me no of pages and no of records for that endpoint.

In a nutshell how to get meta information from order v2 endpoint.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, v2 BC APIs do not have the meta object at the end of a request response so it is a little more challenging.

Personally, I would first use the [Orders Count endpoint](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/orders/orders/getcountorder) to find out how many orders are in the queue I am interested in.

I would then use the [Orders endpoint](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/orders/orders/getallorders) and use a query parameter of `status_id` to get the orders I am interested in and `page` (and probably `limit`) to iterate through the order data.

For more info please check out the [BigCommerce Developer docs](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/orders).

I hope this has helped.